# Sign convention for the Lagrangian of a free massive point particle in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, conventions, point-particles

As far as I understand, the Lagrangian of a massive free particle in the context of general relativity is the following:

$$L=-mc\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}\dfrac{dx^\mu}{dt}\dfrac{dx^\nu}{dt}}.$$

But is this the correct expression in general, or is it only valid for a particular signature of the metric, more precisely for $(+---)?$ My question arose after trying to compute the canonical momentum using this Lagrangian, and obtaining a result with an extra minus sign, which I suspect could come from using the $(-+++)$ signature for the metric.

Comment: To figure this kind of thing out, just consider a simple special case like a particle at rest in flat spacetime. In that case, $dx^0/dt = 1$ and $dx^i/dt = 0$, so your expression becomes $L = - m c \sqrt{g_{00}}$. Of course, the thing inside the square root should be positive, so this Lagrangian applies in the $(+---)$ convention.

Comment: @knzhou Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was looking for. So, all I should do is add an extra minus sign inside the square root if I'm using the $(-+++)$ convention for the metric, right?

Comment: @WildFeather - yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there should just be an absolute value sign inside the square root.